# Write text at the 8th line in file

Tags: python, linux, file-handling

I want to write a comment in several files always on line 8. I tried this but it only writes it in the first file:

```
# insert comment to explain change
comment = now+":  Legal Litres changed to "+legalLitresTxt+"\n" 
commentCounter = 0

try:
    for i in mdcArray:


        line = ""

        Qqfile = glob.glob("/shares/web/vm3618/optiload/prog/MDC"+i+"/*/"+hexFile) 
        outFile = Qqfile[0]+".new"
        print i

        #read /shares/web/vm3618/optiload/prog/i/*/Hexfile
        for files in Qqfile:
            with open(files) as readFile:
                    content = readFile.readlines()

                    writer = open(outFile, 'w')

                    for line in content:
                       commentCounter += 1

                       if commentCounter == 8:
                           writer.write(comment)
```

Could someone explain why it only does this for the first file in the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start from `0` again.
Move:

```
commentCounter = 0
```

in front of

```
for line in content:
```

i.e.

```
commentCounter = 0
for line in content:
```

Your code should look like this (There could many more improvements. Not done here for educational purposes.):

```
comment = now+":  Legal Litres changed to "+legalLitresTxt+"\n" 
try:
    for i in mdcArray:
        line = ""
        Qqfile = glob.glob("/shares/web/vm3618/optiload/prog/MDC"+i+"/*/"+hexFile) 
        outFile = Qqfile[0]+".new"
        print i
        #read /shares/web/vm3618/optiload/prog/i/*/Hexfile
        for files in Qqfile:
            with open(files) as readFile:
                    content = readFile.readlines()
                    writer = open(outFile, 'w')
                    commentCounter = 0
                    for line in content:
                        commentCounter += 1
                        if commentCounter == 8:
                            writer.write(comment)
```